# Как получить ширину элемента в пикселях?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, width

Есть элемент `div`, в CSS файле у него прописано свойство `width: 90%`.

Kак в JS получить ширину этого элемента в пикселях?

Comment: Если есть jquery `$('div').innerWidth();`

Comment: @AndrewB Мне на чистом нужно было, но спасибо :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ну примерно так:

```
document.querySelector('.myDiv').offsetWidth
```

подробнее о разных вариантах ширины, например тут https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics

Answer (score 9):

В зависимости, какую ширину вы хотите получить, можно использовать различные свойства:

- `offsetWidth` - это ширина блока, включая все padding, border, но без margin.
- `clientWidth` - это ширина блока, включая padding, но без border, margin и без scroll. Если блоки инлайновые, то ширина блока будет равна 0.
- `getBoundingClientRect().width` - это ширина блока высчитывается по принципу `clientWidth`, но даёт дробное число.

Так что, в данном случае можно ответить тремя ответами:

```
document.querySelector('.myDiv').offsetWidth
document.querySelector('.myDiv').clientWidth
document.querySelector('.myDiv').getBoundingClientRect().width
```